# СПП с придаточным причины?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Пахнет грешный человек пуще всякой скотины, потому что жрет всякую всячину.

Расчлененное спп, придаточное причины. Союз - потому что.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваши рассуждения, как обычно, правильны. Почему вы постоянно сомневаетесь?

Comment: Не знаю...Может быть, мне нужна поддержка:)

Вам очень благодарна!!! очень-очень))